# What's the best way to rewrite traffic from domainA.com/foo to domainB.com/bar while properly rewriting cookies and redirects?

Tags: rewrite, cookies

We have a number of sites that have blogs, like

- domainA.com/blog
- domainB.com/blog

and we host the blogs on wordpress multi user:

- our-separate-wordpress-site.com/domaina_blog
- our-separate-wordpress-site.com/domainb_blog

for SEO reasons we really, really want domainA.com/blog to be the blog url, not the other path.

But we don't see any examples where this is done, because we need not to just rewrite the traffic, but cookies as well... is this possible with a webserver or a reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any half-decent reverse proxy will rewrite the cookie paths for you as well (it's pretty fundamental to being able to reverse proxy things successfully).

Comment: Chad doesn't see examples, do you have any?